# ReactiveCosmosRepository delete functions not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb

I'm building a Spring Boot app using CosmosDB as my database. All functions work (creating an item, updating one, get all, get by id,...), apart from delete functions. They don't do anything and since their output is void, it doesn't give me any logs either.

The DAO class:

```java
package projects.trashcanapplication.trashcan.dao;

import com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.core.mapping.Container;
import com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.core.mapping.GeneratedValue;
import com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.core.mapping.PartitionKey;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import projects.trashcanapplication.trashcan.models.Address;
import projects.trashcanapplication.trashcan.models.FillStatus;

@Container(containerName = "trashcanData")
public class TrashcanDao{
    @GeneratedValue
    private String attachments;
    private FillStatus fillStatus;
    @GeneratedValue
    private String rid;
    private Address address;
    @Id
    @PartitionKey
    @GeneratedValue
    private String id;
    @GeneratedValue
    private String self;
    @GeneratedValue
    private String etag;
    @GeneratedValue
    private int ts;

    public TrashcanDao(Address address, FillStatus fillStatus) {
        this.fillStatus = fillStatus;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getAttachments(){
        return attachments;
    }

    public FillStatus getFillStatus(){
        return fillStatus;
    }

    public String getRid(){
        return rid;
    }

    public Address getAddress(){
        return address;
    }

    public String getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public String getSelf(){
        return self;
    }

    public String getEtag(){
        return etag;
    }

    public int getTs(){
        return ts;
    }
}
```

The repository

```java
package projects.trashcanapplication.trashcan.repositories;

import com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.repository.ReactiveCosmosRepository;
import projects.trashcanapplication.trashcan.dao.TrashcanDao;

public interface TrashcanRepository extends ReactiveCosmosRepository<TrashcanDao, String> {

}
```

The service calling the repository

```java
package projects.trashcanapplication.trashcan.services;

import com.azure.cosmos.models.PartitionKey;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import projects.trashcanapplication.trashcan.dao.TrashcanDao;
import projects.trashcanapplication.trashcan.models.Trashcan;
import projects.trashcanapplication.trashcan.repositories.TrashcanRepository;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Slf4j
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TrashcanServiceImpl implements TrashcanService {
    private final TrashcanRepository trashcanRepository;
    private final TrashcanMapper trashcanMapper;


    public Flux<Trashcan> getAllTrashcans() {
        return trashcanRepository.findAll().map(trashcanMapper::fromDaoToTrashcan);
    }

    public Mono<Trashcan> getTrashcanById(String id) {
        return trashcanRepository.findById(id).map(trashcanMapper::fromDaoToTrashcan);
    }

    public String createTrashcan(Trashcan trashcan) {
        TrashcanDao saveTrashcan = trashcanMapper.fromTrashcanToDao(trashcan);
        trashcanRepository.save(saveTrashcan).subscribe();
        return saveTrashcan.getId();
    }

    public void deleteTrashcan(String id) {
        trashcanRepository.deleteById(id, new PartitionKey(id));
        log.info(String.format("Deleted trashcan %s", id));
    }
}
```

I have a dataloader temporarily set up to populate my DB with an item upon running the app. The deleteAll() function doesn't work here either.

```java
package projects.trashcanapplication.trashcan.services;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import projects.trashcanapplication.trashcan.dao.TrashcanDao;
import projects.trashcanapplication.trashcan.models.Address;
import projects.trashcanapplication.trashcan.models.FillStatus;
import projects.trashcanapplication.trashcan.repositories.TrashcanRepository;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Slf4j
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DataLoader {
    private final TrashcanRepository trashcanRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    void loadData() {
        Address address1 = new Address("Begijnendijk", "3130", "Liersesteenweg", "181");
        trashcanRepository.deleteAll();
        trashcanRepository.save(new TrashcanDao(address1, FillStatus.EMPTY))
                .flatMap(trashcanRepository::save)
                .thenMany(trashcanRepository.findAll())
                .subscribe(trashcan -> log.info(trashcan.getId().toString()))
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need thinking about the deleteAll method funcionality. Spring framework says: reactor.core.publisher.Mono<Void> deleteAll()
Deletes all entities **managed** by the repository.
So on initialization your repo does not manages any entity, so deletes nothing.

Comment: Doesn't it manage the entities already existing in the container? When I'm starting the app, the container already exists and has items in CosmosDB --> shouldn't it delete those items? And that doesn't really explain why the `Mono<Void> deleteById()` function doesn't work, does it?

Comment: I'm just guessing, but spring says: deleteById(K id,
                                             com.azure.data.cosmos.PartitionKey partitionKey)
Deletes an entity by its id and partition key.
So i think this interact with CosmosDB, but deleteAll not, because this works only with managed entities. I'm not sure I got everything right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not subscribing anywhere, so the reactive stream isn't executed.

You could solve that by subscribing manually:

```
trashcanRepository.deleteAll().subscribe()
```

However, this is not a good practice, and certainly not in your `DataLoader` as you can't guarantee the order in which the save/delete-logic is executed (maybe the `TrashcanDao` is saved before you delete everything).

To solve this, you should create a proper reactive stream:

```java
trashcanRepository
    .deleteAll()
    .then(trashcanRepository.save(new TrashcanDao(address1, FillStatus.EMPTY)))
    .thenMany(trashcanRepository.findAll())
    // Your previous subscribe() shouldn't compile since it should contain List<TrashcanDao>
    .subscribe(trashcans -> log.info(trashcans.size()));
```

Comment: This was indeed the solution, I forgot subscribing to the stream. Thanks for the tip on creating proper streams, haven't got much experience there yet, so this definitely helps!